# Фиксированный блок по середине

Tags: html

как сделать блок с текстом по середине экрана но если скролить то этот блок не будет уезжать, не нашел нормальных уроков

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
height:2000px;
}

div {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis architecto aliquid distinctio facilis nulla commodi laboriosam, dolor saepe quos ullam nisi magnam quia facere, suscipit eum a quidem odio. Velit omnis perspiciatis ex perferendis quae tempora quam beatae aliquid veniam rerum ut repudiandae minus error illo, in aut ad repellendus!</div>
```